# Option, in answers, to merge an answer into the question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, answers, convert-to-edit

Thinking of ways to make a common task easier for moderators.

We've seen it a hundred times. A cookie-based user asks a question. Later, they log on from a different machine and cannot edit their question, so they add an answer to leave comments or add details.

A moderator has two choices. They can delete the answer and move on, or...

1. The mod edits the answer
2. The mod copies all the text from the answer
3. The mod switches back and deletes the answer
4. The mod edits the question
5. The mod pastes the text to the bottom of the question

I'd suggest adding an option to the answer to automate this process.  A moderator can click a "Merge with Question" link, which automatically deletes the answer and adds it as an edit to the bottom of the question.

Mistakes can be fixed by simply reverting the edit and undeleting the answer.

Comment: +1 yes please. Though leaving comments does teach the user what to do.

Comment: @ChrisF: But it doesn't solve the problem of having non-answers...

Comment: +1 I'd like to see this too for all of my "early" questions before comments were implemented and we used the answers to facilitate the communication. I'm hitting mod status soon (hopefully) and I can clean up my own junk! 8^D

Comment: @Dillie Congrats on your impending 10k, but he's actually talking about diamond mods; 10k users can't delete answers

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: Ahh, I see now. I guess that's where I was thinking the merge would come in handy. Maybe that's a 20K privilege.

Comment: @Will - it will be useful for old non answers or where the poster hasn't come back, hence my up-vote. However, in the first instance I would still leave a comment.

Comment: @Dillie-O: I think, since it can be reverted easily, it should be a 10k+ mod tool.

Comment: @Will: You'll get no complaints from me on that one 8^D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is available to moderators now under the mod "convert to edit" menu item.